# Identify bounced EmailMessage (EWS)

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Is there a way to accurately identity bounced back email notifications in a mailbox using EWS? So far I`ve looked at the message headers and nothing seems to indicate that the message is an email bounce notification.

I also looked at the [`Item`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item_members(v=exchg.80).aspx) and the [`EmailMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage_members(v=exchg.80).aspx) members and haven't found anything useful (I may have missed something).

I could always parse the sender which always says 'Email Delivery System' or the subject line or even the message body, but I'm looking for a cleaner way to do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the [ItemClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.itemclass(v=exchg.80).aspx) property.

This corresponds to PR_MESSAGE_CLASS MAPI property. [This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee200767(v=exchg.80).aspx) provides some values for this property. You can find there a list of message classes for different types of messages. Some of them are for Non-Delivery reports, which I think is what you want.

It seems that if this property value starts with "REPORT.IPM" and ends with ".NDR" then its a Non-delivery report.

Comment: The actual item type is REPORT.IPM.Note.NDR (according to OutlookSpy)

Comment: @noonand, take a look at the provided link. There are multiple classes that are for non-delivery reports.

Comment: Nitpicker's corner here but the OP specifically talks about bounced **email** notifications not (for example) meeting requests. Unless you're counting S/MIME encrypted emails there's only one in the provided link, REPORT.IPM.NOTE.NDR